# Inkscape: rectangle with rainbow fill

Tags: inkscape, shapes, gradient

I'd like to create a shape gradiently filled with visible light spectrum colors - from red to blue. I am using Inkscape. When I try to specify gradient from red to blue - it chooses a weird color path. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Would you please make an [edit] showing us the attempt you made?

Comment: The answer given below worked just fine: I used https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Spectrum.svg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with the algorithm that InkScape and other graphics programs use to create gradients, namely (pseudo-code):

```
var gradient = []
var firstColor, secondColor, steps
for i in range(steps):
  p = i/steps
  R = firstColor.R * p + secondColor.R * (1 - p)
  G = firstColor.G * p + secondColor.G * (1 - p)
  B = firstColor.B * p + secondColor.B * (1 - p)
  gradient.push((R,G,B))
```

The spectrum of visible light doesn't work this way though, because real world color isn't RGB. RGB is a method to trick the eyes to see many colors with few colors, just like CMYK.

Now technically, your question has no answer, [because](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum#Color_display_spectrum)...

> Color displays (e.g. computer monitors and televisions) cannot
>   reproduce all colors discernible by a human eye. Colors outside the
>   color gamut of the device, such as most spectral colors, can only be
>   approximated.

But let's say you want to make the approximation in InkScape. Unfortunately, you can only do this by making a big gradient with all of the colors, the SVG standard has no flag for "visible light gradients".

Using [this image from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cc/Spectrum.svg)...

[image: spectrum edited in inkscape]

You can move the two control points around until they only show the gradient from red to blue :)

[image: new spectrum]

Alternatively, you could use the Gradient Editor to flip the order of the colors and delete all the colors before and after red and blue.